# database without server side database

Tags: javascript, database

I have a lot of images on a web server characterized by their name. Every file belongs to several categories, everyone in a category group. For example:

```
group_fruit = ["apple", "banana", "pear"];
group_color = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
group_origin = ["Italy", "France", "Portugal"];

a blue apple from Italy will be 00_01_00_uniqueid.jpg
```

If I want to find images looking for the categories (e.g. I want a blue or yellow pear from France or Portugal) I can look for the files in the filelist in a simple way.
The problem is when I have a large number of categories groups (e.g. 10) with a lot of categories each (i.e. 10), given that I can download only a filelist of **100 items at a time**. In such case I could have a query which generates 10^10 possible answers (worst case).

Given that anything near the worst case would be however difficult to manage, I though to proceed as following:

I make several xml files named using categories from the first five groups, where I store the number of images with that categories AND the other five categories from the remaining groups. For example

```
01_00_03_00_04.xml contains:
    01_00_03_00_04_00_02_04_05_07 = 3
    01_00_03_00_04_04_04_03_00_08 = 12
    01_00_03_00_04_05_08_09_01_02 = 5
```

that means that I have 12 images with 01_00_03_00_04_04_04_03_00_08 categories, for example.
In this way, if I'm looking for specific characteristics, I can download the xmls which are compatible for first five groups of characteristic I'm looking for and then I can search every xml to find if there are results for every possible combination of categories.
In the worst case I will search 10^5 xml for 10^5 categories each.

The solution of using a single big xml with all files is not applicable because it would be too big to download (big delay).
The solution of downloading a list for every possible category combination would be too slow (because I can have several combinations without results, so the user will expect too much time to see first results).
This is why I though to adopt an intermediate solution.

I know that the best way is to use a database, but I'd like to find a client side solution in order to not overload cheap servers.

EDIT: the question is: do you have any idea for a more efficient approach?

Thank you for your patience

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Oh, yes :facepalm: , I mean: do you have any idea for a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to create a object that contains the possible combinations:

```js
var combinations = {
    1:{
        1:[1,2,3],
        2:[1,2,3],
        3:[1,2,3]
    },
    2:{
        1:[1,2,3],
        3:[1,2,3]
    },
    3:{
        1:[2,3],
        2:[1,3],
        3:[1,2]
    },
    /*
    fruit_number:{
        color_number:[origin, origin, origin],
        color_number:[origin, origin]
    }
    */
}
var fruit = ["apple", "banana", "pear"];
var color = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var origin = ["Italy", "France", "Portugal"];

for(var f in combinations){
    for(var c in combinations[f]){
        for(var o in combinations[f][c]){
            console.log("A",color[c-1],fruit[f-1],"from",origin[combinations[f][c][o]-1])
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be pretty, but I think it's as efficient as you'll get.

Comment: I don't understand the answer or I think that my question was not so clear... The user wants all the images with some characteristic, but if he selects a lot of categories he will have a huge amount of possible combinations. Is it possible to store locally a so huge number? And even if it could be possible, should I try to download every image to know if it's present or not?  Perhaps I should programmatically limitate the number of combinations, but how to chose the ones that are present without looking at the file list?

Comment: It's quite possible to store relatively massive amounts of data, client-side (Especially if it's just a bulk of numbers, like the object in my answer) Trying to download every image is a bad idea, I think a better option would be to build a data object server-side, then send it to the client.

Comment: Do you mean building a data object based on all data or on the data searched by the client? The first would be very heavy, even if can be done asynchronously, the second would require some server-side computation proportional to the number of clients (that I'm trying to avoid). However, do you think that JSON (I think you are talking about it, even if I never worked with it) would be far better than XML?

Comment: I'll answer to my last question by myself: yes, definitely http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

Comment: Then make sure you only build the data object once, and cache that.

Comment: not the whole database, however (too huge): I think I should split the database into different file according to some intelligent criteria